# How do I generate multiple pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I want to generate several pdf files just by clicking on a button, but all the time, it's a single file that generates as the return statement stops the function.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
public function printPDF()
    {
        $fiches = FichePaiesInfos::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        foreach ($fiches as $fiche) {
            $data = [
                'name' => $fiche->personnelsInfos->name,
                'firstname' => $fiche->personnelsInfos->firstname,
                'fiche' => $fiche
            ];
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.pdf_view', $data);
        }
        return $pdf->download('fiche' . '_' . time() . '.pdf');;
    }
```

Comment: you can only send one file per HTTP request.

Comment: 1. I think you cannot send more than one files in one request because the headers are sent for one file, 2. you need save the file in your for each after the loadView and then probably you should to zip all of the files and then sent the download for all the files

Answer (score 0):

should you not just put

```
$pdf->download('fiche' . '_' . time() . '.pdf');
```

inside your loop and remove the return all together?

or if you want to return all of the pdfs, create a collection and after

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.pdf_view', $data);
```

add $pdf to the collection, then edit

```
return $pdf->download('fiche' . '_' . time() . '.pdf');;
```

to be return collection;